# Cargar/mostrar un txt en un datagridview a través de un button (Visual Studio) C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, datagridview

tengo un problema.

Tengo un ejercicio en el que debo cargar un archivo de texto .txt (el .txt ya contiene información) y mostrar esa información en un datagridview, ya cree un datatable pero no me muestra el txt.

el datagriedview se llama "dgvDatos"  y el textbox donde pongo la ruta "txtArchivo"

Al correr mi programa no me sale ningún error, siemplemente al darle al button me aparece mi datatable vacía.

Todo está dentro de un button llamado "btnEjecutar"

```
        try
           {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\gisse\Desktop\datos.txt");
            DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string filePath, int numberOfColumns)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column" + (col + 1).ToString()));

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                var cols = line.Split(',');

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex > 4; cIndex++)
                {
                    dr[cIndex] = cols[cIndex];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            return dt;
        }

            dgvDatos.DataSource = ConvertToDataTable
                    (@"C:\Users\gisse\Desktop\datos.txt", 3);
            dgvDatos.Show();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excepción: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Mira la consola a ver si te esta dando error al cargar el fichero

Comment: , sino comprueba que entra en el bucle donde cargas las filas de la tabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comprueba que los la tabla tenga datos por ejemplo mostrandolos por consola con este codigo:

```
      public static void Mostar(DataTable dt)
    {
        DataRow[] currentRows = dt.Select(null, null, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
    
        if (currentRows.Length < 1)
            Console.WriteLine("No hay datos en la tabla");
        else
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                Console.Write("\t{0}", column.ColumnName);
    
            Console.WriteLine("\tRowState");
    
            foreach (DataRow row in currentRows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                    Console.Write("\t{0}", row[column]);
    
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + row.RowState);
            }
        }

}
```

Y si no los tiene prueba a cambiar esta linea:

> for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex > 4; cIndex++)

por esta:

```
    for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < numberOfColumns; cIndex++)
```

Comment: Hola, cambie ese for como me dijiste pero al poner cIndex < numerOfColumns ya no me crea el datatable, no hay ningun error pero al darle al button ya no me crea las columnas, (Mi txt tiene solo 3 columnas).

Comment: has cambiado el for que crea las columnas y tienes que cambiar solo el for que lee las filas, seguramente.

Comment: Ya confirmé que ambas cosas salgan bien por separado, crear la tabla y que el txt se muestre en un textbox de prueba, el problema es que no se me muestra en un datagridview ya con la tabla hecha. Cambie la parte de `StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\gisse\Desktop\datos.txt");
            DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string filePath, int numberOfColumns)` por `string ubicacion = (@"C:\Users\gisse\Desktop\datos.txt");
            string leer = File.ReadAllText(ubicacion);
            txtArchivo.Text = leer;`  El "txtArchivo" es el textbox de prueba y si funciona, pero no con grid

Comment: Asegurate que dgvDatos.DataSource =dt o a la variable que ahora contenga el DataTable